# how create homey flow with dynamic arguments

Tags: homey

I would know how I can create an [Homey Flow Card](https://apps.developer.homey.app/the-basics/flow) with [arguments](https://apps.developer.homey.app/the-basics/flow/arguments) populated dynamically.

Than you

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change what arguments a Flow card has based on the values entered by the user. It is recommended to create multiple Flow cards with the combinations of arguments that you want to support. Users can then pick which Flow card they want to use.

An example would be a Flow card that creates a HTTP request. Instead of creating a card where the user enters the HTTP Method, you can create multiple Flow cards for GET, POST etc.
This way you can chose to only add an argument for the request body to the POST request card.

Hope this answers your question, if I misunderstood please let me know.